# Calculating percentage in java

Tags: java

If I want to calculate 76/266 = 28.57% in java, what's the best data type to use?

So far, I have:

```
int x = 76;
int y = 266;
float z = (x * 100) / y;
```

But doing this, I get 28.0 as an answer. I need to get an answer rounded to the nearest hundredth place. Thanks.

Comment: Integer arithmetic strikes yet again!

Comment: replace `100` with `100.0`

Comment: declare x and y as floats

Comment: make `x` and `y` float.

Comment: http://ideone.com/v0gehG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use [java.math.BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for your calculation. I believe this is the highest precision datatype in Java

```
BigDecimal d1 = new BigDecimal(67.67);
BigDecimal d2 = new BigDecimal(67.68);
BidDecimal d3 = d1.divide(d2); // d1 + d2 is invalid
```

Comment: using bigdecimal will also help you avoid pitfalls associated with floating pointing arithmetic.

Comment: Might want to mention that you'll want to be careful for `ArithmeticExceptions` if the result is an infinitely repeating decimal, unless you have limited precision.

Comment: When using BigDecimal you should use the constructor that takes String as parameter. If you use the constructor which takes double the BigDecimal you get back is the exact representation as the double you passed in!

Comment: @user2360087, A BigDecimal "can" take a String but it "may" take any number of arguments. Please see [the Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for the fairly lengthy list of valid Types.

Comment: ` BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(1);
        value = value.divide(new BigDecimal(3));` will fail! Try.

Answer (score 6):

In Java and some other programming languages, there is something called *integer arithmetic*, which says that if you do (in your case):

```
int / int = int
```

In your code, you are doing

```
(int * int) / int   <=>   int / int = int
```

## Solutions:

**Method 1:** Something you can do to get a float is to use a `float` operand. In your case it can be the `100`:

```
float z = (x * 100.0f) / y;
```

Here, the operation is

```
(int * float) / int   <=>   float / int = float
```

**Method 2:** Another way to solve this is to *cast* an integer to a float:

```
float z = (x * 100) / (float)y;   // int * int / float = float
float z = (float)x * 100 / y;   // float * int / int = float
```

**Method 3:** As @webSpider mentioned in his answer, you can just declare the variables `x` and `y` as `float` to avoid these problems.

**Edit:** To round your `float` result, you can try this:

```
float z = Math.round(result * 100) / 100f;
```

where the number of zeros of `100` is the number of decimal places. Note that `100f` will be a `float` because of the postfix `f`.

Comment: x and y have to be ints in my case.

Comment: Then you can use one of the two first methods. Note that casting won't modify the variable.

Comment: Ok, after that how do I round?

Answer (score 3):

```
float x = 76;
float y = 266;
float z = x * 100 / y;
//=28.571428
```

If you want to round it, use:

```
double x = 76;
double y = 266;
double z = Math.round(x * 100 / y* 100.0) / 100.0;
//=28.57
```

btw, as you see you don't need the parenthesis in your calculation there is a [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) ...

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in your code is,

multiply an integer x to 100 and then divide the result by integer y. So their output will be integer only.

Then you are storing this int result in a float variable. So it just adds `.0` to your result.

To get the result you want you can do any of the following,

```
1.      int x = 76;
        int y = 266;
        float z = (x * 100.0f) / y;
```

`Note do not write 100.0 because it will be treated as a double number so you will get loss of precision error`

```
2.     float x = 76;
       int y = 266;
       float z = (x * 100) / y;

3.     float x = 76;
       float y = 266;
       float z = (x * 100) / y;
```